# Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAppLinkResolver'

Tags: swift

Yesterday I updated Xcode to Version 7.3 (7D175) and suddenly my apps is not building any more. My dead line is near and I can't build the apps :-(

I tried to change Build Settings to:

- allow non-modular includes in framework modules = yes
- enable modules = no

My pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
use_frameworks!

#Parse, Facebook, Twitter
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

installed cocoapods-0.39.0

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts (1.6.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.10.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.10.1)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.10.1)
Using Parse (1.13.0)
Using ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.11.1)
Using ParseTwitterUtils (1.10.0)
Using ParseUI (1.2.0)
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

I changed back app build settings to:

```
allow non-modular includes in framework modules = no
enable modules = yes
```

And I changed the Pods > ParseFacebookUtilsV4 as follow in the image below and everything is fine again. I hope that can help you too.

[See the screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfQEj.png)

It worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me, specifically the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 screenshot